# Oracle APEX - Interactive Grid - get the return value of the select list from each record

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex, apex-code

My Interactive Grid has column caled "EMPL_STAT1".

I use the code below to get the return value of the select list from selected record.

Works fine but I was wondering how to change that code to get the return value of the select list from each record (not selected only) in "EMPL_STAT1" column?

Could you give me any advice?

```
var reg = apex.region('ig_emp').widget();
var grid = reg.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid");
var model = reg.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").model;
var selectedRecords = grid.getSelectedRecords();

for (i = 0; i < selectedRecords.length; i++)

    {
        record = model.getRecord(selectedRecords[i][0]);
        itemcodeField = model.getFieldKey("EMPL_STAT1");
        alert(record[itemcodeField].v);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript you shared, gets the selected row records only.
Let's say my IG's static ID is `igTest`

```
var model = apex.region("igTest").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid").model;
model.forEach(function(igrow) {
   console.log(igrow[model.getFieldKey("FIRST_NAME")]);
});
```

This will loop through all the records in the IG.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to implement your solution in my code before, but the problem is to combine loop through all the records with  getting the return value of the select list simultaneous. I wasn't able to build the correct code.